# Sending Mail via Mail Server Asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, email, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to send mail through mail server ( available in fatcow).

```
Username:    info@efernssolutions.com
SMTP Server:     smtp.hostname.com
SMTP Port:   587
```

I used the follwing code to send mail ,

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {
   MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
     try
        {
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress("kishore.eferns@gmail.com"));
                message.From = new MailAddress("info@efernssolutions.com");
                message.Subject = "Test mail";
                message.Body = "this is the mail sended through my c#.net program";
                message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Port = 587; 
                client.Host = "smtp.hostname.com";
                System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@efernssolutions.com", "password");// is u are using Gmail
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = nc;
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
                client.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ;
            }
        }
```

When i use gmail server the code works fine and i received mail.

But it is not working with my email server.

I get the error,

```
the remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure
```

Is there anything left to do to make it work?

Please help,

Thank you

Comment: As first check I will suggest to check if your SSL certificate is correctly installed on your server

Comment: thank u..u r right...that was the problem... I can accept ur answer if u put it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As first check I will suggest to check if your SSL certificate is correctly installed on your server